# Can we set urlfetch deadline while using Google Drive API v2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

dear all

My application error logs such as the one show below:

```
Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=...
```

I understand this is caused by deadline settings of UrlFetch. And I was wondering if I can change the deadline temporarily just for this API call without affecting other part of my application. After that, I was wondering if following code shall work:

```
self.http = self.credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(timeout=30))
self.gService = build('drive', 'v2', http=self.http, developerKey=getApiKey())
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that wouldn't work.

Internally, app engine's httplib2 uses urlfetch. However, your parameter at httplib2 would not be passed to urlfetch. I know it is painful to use Drive API with default 5 second deadline... When I need to develop any Drive application on app engine, I just use urlfetch without google-api-python-client.